# Jquery datatable with tri color rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried jquery datatable with tri colored rows which is repeating alternatively.But i got only two colored rows repeating.

[Tried jquery datatable with tri colored rows](http://jsfiddle.net/SAJINA/zzf61auq/11/)
I'm using property even/odd for coloring

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#example tr:even").css("background-color", "LightYellow");
 $("#example tr:odd").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
});
```

Comment: You can use `nth-child()`, also having multiple `document.ready` handlers in a single file is redundant - include all the code in a single one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use jquery to implement this CSS is much suitable for that job. try this.

```
/*tri color rows*/
table.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(3n+1)  {background-color: #FFCCCC;}
table.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(3n+2)  {background-color: #99D6AD;}

table.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(3n)    {background-color: #EBD6FF;}
th {
background: #aaf;
}
thead{
    background: #aaf;
}
/* End: tri color rows*/
```

[check this Demo in js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/zzf61auq/14/)

Comment: The most efficient answer, although be aware this won't work for < IE9